# Adressing files/directories in ogr2ogr using OSGeo4W shell?

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr, shell

I want to convert a .pbf-file (*freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf*) into a SpatialLite Data Base using ogr2ogr. The file is located at *W:\geodaten\UG*

I open *OSGeo4W.bat* in the directory *C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18.*.
I enter following code:

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES basemap_ug.db freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf
```

However, this does not work; I get:

> C:>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES basemap_ug.db freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf
>
> ERROR 4: sqlite3_open(basemap_ug.db) failed: unable to open database file
>
> ERROR 1: SQLite driver failed to create basemap_ug.db

Probably I need to specify the directory of the file. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you miss rights for creating a new data file into c:\ root. Create a new directory, for example c:\data, and try again with c:\data\basemap_ug.db.

Comment: I am very new to all of this. I created a new folder (c:\data). How do I tell the shell to write the file into this directory?

Comment: I tried `C:\>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES C:\data basemap_ug.db freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf`which gives me `FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource 'basemap_ug.db' with the following drivers.` and then lists a large set of drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up making the file location explicit by
`C:\>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES W:\geodaten\Promotion_UG\basemap_ug.db freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf`
Thank you, @user30184

Comment: You might as well put the full path before the source file. Then you can start the command from whatever folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since the file has the extension .osm.pbf you also need to specify the filename including the whole extension in your command like that:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES basemap_ug.db freiburg-regbez-latest.osm.pbf
```

Comment: This is true, of course. I corrected it, but it still doesn't work. I updated the question.